# Insert data into google fit failing: UNKNOWN_AUTH_ERROR/NEEDS_OAUTH_PERMISSIONS

Tags: google-api, google-fit

I have the following code for inserting hydration data using History Api,

```
public void addHydrationData(int waterVolume){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    float volume = (float)waterVolume/1000f;
    S.L("V F: " + volume + "wv: " + waterVolume);
    final DataSet hydrationDataSet = createDataForRequest(DataType.TYPE_HYDRATION, DataSource.TYPE_RAW,
           volume, startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            S.L("gac isconn: " + googleApiClient.isConnected());
            S.L("gac gcr: " + googleApiClient.getConnectionResult(Fitness.HISTORY_API));
            Status waterInsertStatus = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleApiClient, hydrationDataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if(!waterInsertStatus.isSuccess()){
                S.L("There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
                S.L("WIS: " + waterInsertStatus.getStatusCode());
                if (waterInsertStatus.getStatusCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.NEEDS_OAUTH_PERMISSIONS ||
                        waterInsertStatus.getStatusCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.UNKNOWN_AUTH_ERROR) {
                    try {
                        S.L("Need oauth");
                        waterInsertStatus.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, S.REQUEST_OAUTH);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        S.L("SIE");
                    }
                } else{
   
                }
            } else {
                S.L("Successfully added data");
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
08-19 14:51:36.423 4594-4594/in.jiyofit.gfit D/CCC: V F: 0.25wv: 250
08-19 14:51:36.454 4594-5585/in.jiyofit.gfit D/CCC: gac isconn: true
08-19 14:51:36.454 4594-5585/in.jiyofit.gfit D/CCC: gac gcr: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null, message=null}
08-19 14:51:36.928 4594-5585/in.jiyofit.gfit D/CCC: There was a problem inserting the dataset.
08-19 14:51:36.928 4594-5585/in.jiyofit.gfit D/CCC: WIS: 5005
08-19 14:51:36.929 4594-5585/in.jiyofit.gfit D/CCC: Need oauth
```

Earlier I was getting the status code as 5000, now I am getting 5005. Both have to be resolved in the following way as suggested by Google

> Status code denotes that the request is missing desired OAuth permissions.
>
> If an app does not have the required OAuth access for a specific API request, the request will fail with this status code. When this occurs, apps can use the pending intent inside the status object to request the necessary access before retrying the request.
>
> Sample usage when access is missing for a request:

```
 PendingResult<Result> pendingResult = FitnessApi.readData(fitnessRequest);
 Result result = pendingResult.await(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 Status = result.getStatus();

 if (!status.isSuccess()) {
      if (status.getStatusCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.NEEDS_OAUTH_PERMISSIONS) {
          status.startResolutionForResult(
                  myActivity,
                  MY_ACTIVITYS_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE);
      }
 }
```

But nothing is happening when the `startResolutionForResult` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add `new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE)` in `requestScopes` in `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder`. Datatype `TYPE_HYDRATION` belongs to the scope FITNESS_NUTRITION. The app also needs to be uninstalled and reinstalled to add the new scope to the account.